# Least squares partial derivatives to matrix form

Tags: partial-derivative, regression, least-squares, pseudoinverse

*I've been led to believe* that it is in fact possible to convert the least squares approximation from their *partial derivatives = 0* sum form to the matrix form $\overline{b}=(M^TM)^{-1}M^T\overline{y}$. Apparently one does not get the matrix M, but combined $M^TM$ and $M^T\overline{y}$.

How might one go about the job?

For example, let the model be: $a+b\cdot \sin x$
$$S(a,b) = \sum_1^n{(y_i-a-b\cdot \sin x_i)^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial S(a,b)}{\partial a}=\sum_1^n{2(y_i-a-b\cdot \sin x_i)(-1)}$$
$$\frac{\partial S(a,b)}{\partial b}=\sum_1^n{2(y_i-a-b\cdot \sin x_i)(-\sin x_i)}$$

$$\sum y = \sum a + \sum b\sin x$$
$$\sum y\sin x = \sum a\sin x + \sum b\sin x\sin x$$

Then what?

Comment: Wikipedia has the derivation written out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Derivation_of_the_normal_equations); perhaps you could try making sense of that

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks! After some thought and comparison it began to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Derivation_of_the_normal_equations) provided in the comments I got it as it was actually pretty close. So by taking the constants out of the summations, one can easily bring the equation system to first a vectorized form and finally to a matrix form.

$$\sum y = a\sum 1 + b\sum \sin x$$
$$\sum y\sin x = a\sum \sin x + b\sum \sin^2 x$$
And so:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\sum y \\ \sum y\sin x\end{bmatrix} = a\begin{bmatrix}\sum 1 \\ \sum \sin x\end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix}\sum\sin x \\ \sum\sin^2x\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}\sum y \\ \sum y\sin x\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\sum 1 & \sum\sin x \\ \sum\sin x & \sum \sin^2 x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$$